# FabricJS Drawing mode and Hammer.JS Pinch creates unwanted, non objects

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, hammer.js

The task is to create a drawing app. If the Fabric's drawing mode is activated, and I try to pinch using hammer.js's Pinch event, a weird artifact appears, that does not show when I call getObjects() on canvas. The code is as follows :

```
  let hammer = new Hammer.Manager(this.canvas.upperCanvasEl); // Initialize hammer
  let pinch = new Hammer.Pinch(); // Initialize pinch
  hammer.add([pinch]); 

  hammer.on('pinch',  (ev) => {
    let point = new fabric.Point(ev.center.x, ev.center.y);
    let delta = this.zoom * ev.scale;

    this.canvas.zoomToPoint(point, delta);
  }); 

  this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
        hoverCursor: 'pointer',
        selection: false,
        allowTouchScrolling: false
  }); // create the canvas

  this.canvas.setBackgroundColor('rgba(255,255,255, 1)', this.canvas.renderAll.bind(this.canvas)); // add a white background
  this.canvas.isDrawingMode = true;  // enable drawing mode


  this.canvas.on('mouse:down',  (o) => {

   if(o.e.touches && o.e.touches.length > 1) { // more than 1 finger
      this.canvas.isDrawingMode = false;   // When a mouse down event is detected - disable FreeDrawing mode. At this point the (non) object is already created. 
    }
  });
```

If I try to get all the objects from canvas, the wrongfully unwanted items will not show up :

```
  this.canvas.getObjects().map((o)=> {
     // The items are expected here, and maybe delete the ones that have less that 3-5 polypoints .. but they do not show up. 
  });
```

If you draw anything else after this, the "point" disappears.

Video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrxFfrQkDPU

Answer (score 3):

Inside `mouse:down:before` handler disable drawing mode.

```
canvas.on('mouse:down:before',  (o) => {
 if(o.e.touches && o.e.touches.length > 1) { // more than 1 finger
   Instance.canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
 }
});
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks. Unfortunately, the same unwanted dot appears. If I do not check for multiple fingers, it works ... but I need to disable it only in that case.

Comment: @Mike fabric drawing will work only with one finger touch, seems there is bug, trying to solve ;)

Comment: still haven't managed to find a solution for this. Have you ?

Comment: @Mike put this link in your github issue as well.